# Lost all my files

Tags: upgrade

Following the routine Ubuntu upgrade request on Jan 19, when I reopened Ubuntu, I could not find any of my Document files or images. I suspect they may be hiding somewhere, but I don't know where. I could not access my own blogspot blogs either. Solutions welcomed!

Comment: Is there anything where your files should be? Where are the files supposed to be (for example `~/Documents`, `/tmp`/, etc.)? Did a `ls -a` show anything in the directory where the files are supposed to be? What do your blogs have to do with missing local files? Normal software update or distribution upgrade (13.04 -> 13.10)?

Comment: Do you anything in your home directory? Also what is the output of `du -s /home`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the files are still somewhere on your hard drive (during a routine upgrade files are not thrown away) you could try:

> sudo updatedb

this will update a database with everything on your disk. And now you can search using:

> sudo locate name |less

replace name with (part of) the name of a file which you lost.

Hopefully it pops up on a different location.

Maybe the location of your documents was not the standard location so the links are now incorrect.